# How to add 3D object (.fbx) in my python web server?

Tags: javascript, html, server, 3d, fbx

I have create a python web server with interface (home.html, in the folder templates). So I try to add a 3D object with extension: .fbx but when I add this, just a black screen appears.
And in the console, I have this error:

***GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403***

***Uncaught TypeError: THREE.FBXLoader is not a constructor
at (index):260:17***

And now this is my html code:

```
<div class="right"></div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Créer la scène
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Créer la caméra
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 5;

        // Créer le rendu
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // Ajouter le rendu à la div "right"
        document.querySelector(".right").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Charger le fichier .fbx
        var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
        loader.load('Rack.fbx', function (object) {
            scene.add(object);
        });

        // Fonction d'animation
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
    </script>
```

And for information, '**Rack.fbx**' is in same folder that home.html.